# How to initialize the input tag dynamically generated by jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

I encountered a problem, that is, I need to **dynamically generate the input tag into a slider**. The following link points to an **HTML** file, which shows my problem in detail.
[this is a link which contains the html content](https://github.com/linsanityHuang/my-question/blob/master/slider.html)
[this link will show you the html](https://svn.veevlink.com/Custom/ManDay/slider.html)

Comment: Can you explain your question little more?

Comment: ok. my question is that the dynamically generate the input tag through jQuery can't transform into the jQuery mobile slider. click the following link, you will find one html file which will tell you my question in details. https://github.com/linsanityHuang/my-question/blob/master/slider.html

Comment: https://svn.veevlink.com/Custom/ManDay/slider.html

Comment: I just executed your code in snippet and it is working fine. can you explain a bit more

Comment: ok, you must notice there is two sliders. the two sliders have the different style because the bottom slider is dynamically generated through jQuery code. however i want the bottom slider looks like the top slider. that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [slider plugin](https://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/) using `$( "input" ).slider();`method. 
You can use `class='ui-shadow-inset ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-slider-input'` to style the dynamically generated input box. 
Hope this will solve your issue.

```js
$(function() {
  $input_node = $("<input id='a' type='number' name='points' value='0' id='points' min='0' max='5' step='0.5' class='ui-shadow-inset ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-slider-input'></input>");
  $("#div").append($input_node);
  
  $("#a").slider();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>


<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="div">
  <input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="0.5"> 
</div>
```

Comment: @JustinHuang Happy coding, let me know if you face any issue. :0

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(function () {
        $input_node = $("#points").clone();
        $("#div").append($input_node);
    })
```